# Disallow categories from this MySQL query

Tags: categories, mysql, query

I'm trying to modify a plugin that generates an archive listing so it shows only one category, making it a single category archive.

The old version of the plugin used a get_posts query, and so it was easy to disallow categories of posts:

```
$rawposts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&category=-4,-6,-7,-9' );
```

The new version of the plugin uses that database query:

```
SELECT ID, post_date, post_date_gmt, comment_status, comment_count FROM 
$wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_password =
```

How do I disallow several categories from a database query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the get_tax_sql() function introduced in WP 3.1:

```
$tax_query = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'terms' => array( 4, 6, 7, 9 ),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
  )
);

$clauses = get_tax_sql( $tax_query, $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

...
"SELECT ID, post_date, post_date_gmt, comment_status, comment_count
FROM $wpdb->posts {$clauses['join']}
WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'post'
{$clauses['where']}
"
...
```

(not tested)